# Installing Linux ubuntu on Hp omen 15

Tags: linux, windows-10, ubuntu, multi-boot, dualboot

I have an HP omen 15-dh1059nr. Is it possible to install ubuntu on it with no issues?

Specs:

- Intel 1-7 10750h
- Nvidia GeForce RTX 2060
- 16gb ram
- Windows 10 UEFI mode

Comment: Also I'm wanting to dual boot but am worried about corruption

Comment: *Could you?* Depends on your level of expertise. This is a matter of opinion, and not a problem that can be fixed in this forum.

Comment: Make sure your backups are up to date, then give it a try. If it fails restore from backup.

Comment: Did you try @AMuffin? I wanted to by a hp omen laptop and wondering if it supports ubuntu or not.

Comment: Yes, I tried dual booting and it had perfect hardware support (at least for my hardware)